# How can you control Kristen FPGA from implementing excess registers?

Tags: fpga

I am using Kristen to generate a Verilog FPGA host interface for a neuromorphic processor.  I have implemented the basic host as follows,

```
<module name= "nmp" duplicate="1000">
        <register name="start0"     type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000000" description="Lower 64 bit start pointer of persitant NMP storage."></register>
        <register name="start1"     type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000020" description="Upper 64 bit start pointer of persitant NMP storage."></register>
        <register name="size"       type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x10000000" description="Size of NMP persitant storage in Mbytes."></register>
        <register name="c_start0"       type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x10000000" description="Lower 64 bit start pointer of cached shared storage."></register>
        <register name="c_start1"       type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000020" description="Upper 64 bit start pointer of cached shared storage."></register>
        <register name="c_size"         type="rdconst" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x10000000" description="Size of cached shared storage in Mbytes."></register>
        <register name="row"        type="rdwr" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000000" description="Configurable row location for this NMP."></register>
        <register name="col"        type="rdwr" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000000" description="Configurable col location for this NMP."></register>
        <register name="threshold"  type="rdwr" mask="0xFFFFFFFF" default="0x00000000" description="Configurable synaptic sum threshold for this instance."></register>
         <memory name="learn"  memsize="0x00004000" type="mem_ack" description="Learning interface - Map input synapsys to node intensity">
            <field name="input_id"         size="22b" description="Input ID this map data is intended for."></field>
            <field name="scale"            size="16b" description="The intensity scale for this input ID."></field>
         </memory>
    </module>
```

The end result is that I am seeing a ton of registers being generated and I have to scale my NMP size down to fit within the constraints of my FPGA.  Is there a way to control the number of registers being generated here?  Obviously I need to store settings for these different fields.  Am I missing something here?

I should add that I am trying to get to a 2048 scale on my NMP but the best I can do is just over a 1000, and not quite 1024.  If I implement without PCIe or host control, I can get to 2048 without issue.

Comment: Hi Nolen, can you explain a little more about what's in your NMP relative to the control logic?  Is it that when you set your NMP to have 1000 instances, that you get 1000 control blocks each with unique stored settings, or is the interface combinitorial , such that if you aren't holding the setting against the instance it won't remember?  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The NMP i have implemented stores its own data for registers and it uses external memory for the region defined as <memory>.

Comment: Ok.  I think I know what is going on.  I'll draw up a picture and post it in an answer here shortly.  I think you will be able to do a simple redefinition in your kristen configuration, but you will most likley have to modify your Verilog instantiation.

Comment: One other question, do you have independent interfaces per NMP instance?

Comment: Each NMP instance has a data, address and an enable.  The address is 32 bit aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each NMP instance has a been coded with a internal register to store data and the configuration you have shown will result in kristen creating Verilog with registers as well.  Effectivley there is a double buffered storage occuring.

[image: Double flops per instance]

Because of this, the number of registers are effectively doubled beyond what they need to be.  One way of dealing with this situation described is to use another RAM interface of 32 bits wide.  I do note that your config calls for 9 x 32 bits words which is a odd size for memory.  There will be some wasted adddress space.  Kristen will create a RAM's on binary boundaries so, you can get a 16x32bit memory region that you can overlay on that interface.  And then a second RAM just like you have already for the learn memory.

```
<module>
    <memory name="regs" memsize="0x10" type="mem_ack" description="Register mapping per NMP instance">
        <field name "start0" size="32b" description="Start0"></field>
        <field name "start1" size="32b" description="Start1"></field>
        ....
        <field name "threshold" size="32b" description="Threshold"></field>
    </memory>
    <memory name="learn"  memsize="0x00004000" type="mem_ack" description="Learning interface - Map input synapsys to node intensity">
        <field name="input_id"         size="22b" description="Input ID this map data is intended for."></field>
        <field name="scale"            size="16b" description="The intensity scale for this input ID."></field>
     </memory>
</module>
```

Generate this and take a look at the new interface.  That should reduce the number of registers generated in your Verilog code and subsequent synthesis.